# SQL table design with contigent constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, many-to-many, database-design

I have a table design problem for which I need a cunning solution.

Let's say I have two tables, with relationship:

```
Contract 1---N Payment
```

Now, let's say I have legacy data that needs to go into these tables. The problem though is that many of the legacy Payment entries are aggregated across mulitple contracts

So we could actually view this as:

New:

```
SomethingAboveContract 1---N Contract 1---N Payment
```

Legacy:

```
SomethingAboveContract 1---N Payment
```

Now, I can get around this by creating an M-N relationship between Contract and Payment.

```
Contract 1---N ContractPayment N---1 Payment
```

(it will be possible for me to identify all the contracts that are linked to the aggregated payment)

This is fine for the legacy data, but I actually do want to enforce the 1-N relationship between Contract and Payment going forward. So, using my very unhandy scribble to illustrate, I would like to do this:

[image]

I.e. where the payment is aggregate, ContractID will be NULL, otherwise it should not be null. In other words, I need to find a way to enforce the following contingencies on the Payment table:

1. ContractID nullable if PaymentID appears in ContractPayment
2. ContractID not nullable if PaymentID does not appear in ContractPayment

I don't know how to do this though.

Even if this is possible, it does seem a bit ugly (which legacy data conversion invariably is). So if anyone has a more elegant solution that would be great. Otherwise, anything that works!

Thanks
Karl

Comment: Since you can't write a DML statement that affects multiple tables, you've got a chicken-and-egg problem here - you can't insert into `ContractPayment` until a row exists in `Payment`, but you can't insert your desired row in Payment since it's got a null `ContractID`, and no rows in `ContractPayment`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I guess you are conveniently omitting `SELECT` from your definition of "DML" :)

Comment: @onedaywhen - since `SELECT` (without `INTO`) doesn't *Manipulate* data, no I don't include `SELECT` in D *M* L. And even if we did include it, are you aware of any way to get a `SELECT` statement to *affect* any table (let alone multiple ones)

Comment: I don't know of a way to specify conditional nullability other than perhaps enforcing this relationship in a trigger, which I do not suggest doing.  (<shudder> Business logic in triggers, also called "How To Shoot Yourself In The Foot And Make Your Co-Workers Hate You!").  Given that you've got the join table between Contract and Payment I don't understand the value of the direct linkage between Contract and Payment.  The foreign keys between the join table, Contract, and Payment do the same thing as the direct link except that they're A) indirect and B) more flexible.  YMMV.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I don't think DML is formally defined e.g. is not part of the SQL Standards. Though you will no doubt find many such as your own that exclude `SELECT` (without `INTO`), I think most do included it e.g. [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language). No big deal, of course :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two (sets of) tables, one for 'legacy' and one going forward. You should be able to define the business rules simply and without the need for nullable columns (SQL's three value logic is a disaster). Privileges could be revoked on the 'legacy' table(s) to help ensure they are not used going forward.

Comment: +1 my first thought exactly.  Two sets of tables.  Also add at least one view to get payments for a contract that combines the two tables.

Comment: +1 for two sets of tables. In the most general case, it can be impossible to get legacy data to fit new constraints. Not only that, but you often need to distinguish legacy data from more current data. When they're in separate tables, that's dead simple.